# solve matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices $A$ and $B$, I was wondering there is a solution for

$XAX=B$,

where $X$ is also a SPD matrix.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think it is always possible?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be rewritten as
$$ (A^{1/2} X A^{1/2})^2 = A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}. $$
So
$$ X = A^{-1/2} (A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^{1/2} A^{-1/2} .$$

Comment: brilliant! Thank you for the help!